# how can set cookie with Ajax/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

i have ajax function like below:

```
$.ajax({
url:"cookie.php",  
type: 'post',
data: {'ok': val},
success:function(data) {
alert(data);
}
});
```

and my cookie.php for setcookie is:

```
$name = "mySite";
$value = "stackoverflow.com";
setcookie($name, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
echo $name."=".$value;
```

with my ajax function `mySite=stackoverflow.com` show in my page but cookie not set in browser. why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cookies are set using the HTTP `Set-Cookie` header, sent in the HTTP response when a page first loads.

This header instructs the browser to store the cookie and send it back in future requests to the server.

When you set the cookie with ajax, the browser doesn't reload the current page, and no new headers are sent.
Instead, a new request is sent in the background with `XMLHttpRequest`, and the cookies are never added to the current page headers, as that page newer reloads and receives the header containing the cookie.

You have to reload the page and get a new set of headers to see the new cookies added in PHP.

There's also the option of setting the cookies in javascript, then they would be visible in the browser right away.

```
document.cookie="mySite=stackoverflow.com; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2015 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```